Tonic of small piece
Obviously, for large polyphony works it is impossible to use the term "tonic".
But if we look at small pieces, like my favourite Bach Cello Suites (especially parts), it seems "tonic of piece" makes sense.
Firstly, the tonic should match the key. So for G major - BWV 1007 it should be G.
But what about octave?
I see that Allemande is ended in G of the Great octave, so I suppose this is the tonic.
But G of the Small octave is also often found in this piece.
So I'm in doubt.
Updated
I study the transitions between degrees of mode, but considering octaves.
So the transition G  → C of the same octave (down),
it is not the same as the transition G  → C next octave (up).
And to make the structure of such transitions I need to choose a tonic of piece considering the octave.

"Obviously, for large polyphony works it is impossible to use the term "tonic"": why?

Tonic refers to the pitch class (i.e., the letter name), not to the specific octave in which that pitch occurs.
Update
Since the question is based on an individual definition of “tonic”, it is up to the asker to construct the definition in a manner consistent with their purpose. There is no standard music-theoretic answer to the question.

Whichever octave sounds a G note/chord is absolutely fine. That doesn't matter - as long as it's a G, that tells what key the piece is in. Usually...
Not sure where 'Great or small' octave comes from though... Maybe it's a specific country's way of defining, but here, it makes no difference.

The great octave is the octave that is traditionally designated using upper case letters, so it corresponds to C2 through B2 in scientific pitch notation (though if you go back far enough, the transition from one octave to the next happened from G to A, and I'm not certain when people started considering that the transition was from B to C).
